# Add all visual studio projects to GitHub and sync them through SkyDrive

Tags: git, github, backup, repository

The title describes almost all my question. I have a lot of VisulStudio projects which I want to add to a Git repository. I have no experience which Git. I tried drag & droping the "Projects" folder of the Visual Studio to GitHub `local` repositories but it created a `.git` directory in my projects root directory. Please describe to me what I need to do to put the repository and sync in in SkyDrive. Should I copy all my projects to `SkyDrive` folder and create the repository there? What is the minimum amount of files I need to copy to `SkyDrive` to perform a full cloud backup?

### Update

When I tried to dropping the `Projects` folder of my `Visual Studio 2012` on the GitHub **application**, it couldn't add the changes. I'm guessing it's because there are so many files inside that folder. (About 4GB in 128,429 Files, 10,170 Folders).

So my question is: *What is the best approach to create Git repositories for all my projects?*
Should I:

1. Create a single bare repository in my SkyDrive folder and a single repository for the `Projects` folder and add/commit/push changes to it.
2. Add a single repository for each project and a single bare repository on the SkyDrive folder?
3. Copy all my projects to SkyDrive folder and create repositories there? (Don't use bare repository at all). And if so, should I use single or multiple repositories?
4. A better solution???

And most importantly, is there an app that can make this process automated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are new to git http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html should help. If a .git file is created in the root directory it is not an issue of worry. You just have to get it pushed with your online repository on git, however a repository of the same directory name should be created on your online git account before you can push it. Incase if you are adding additional folders and files to the git repo you will need to add and commit them first, before you push them.
Also for your help here are a few basic git commands used a lot:
git clone "link of repo"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push/pull origin master

Also here's a link for cheatsheet incase you decide to use git on large extent. http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/git/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only problem is that I don't want to use the GitHub website to push my repository. I want to create my own server and sync it in the cloud.

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you please check it out and see if you could help? I'd very much appreciate it.